# Кроссплатформенный перенос файлов

Tags: c++, файлы, передача-данных, кроссплатформенность

Есть какой-нибудь легальный способ кроссплатформенного переноса папок/файлов в C++? Целевые платформы: Linux, Win32, Mac OS X. Желательно именно способы переноса, а не copy/remove, т.к. внутри одного диска простой перенос будет моментальным.

Comment: Вам нужен [boost::filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#rename).

Comment: Пробовал, но он может только в копирование, а нужен именно перенос файлов

Comment: А rename пробовали?

Comment: Пробовал, но система ругается: SIGABRT Aborted

Comment: А если и работает, то конкретно переименование в одной папке, а нужен перенос между папками

Comment: SIGABRT программа получает, если в ней что-то не то. Поскольку в бусте вряд ли ошибка, скорее всего что-то не так с вашим кодом.

Comment: Что не так с этой строчкой? boost::filesystem::rename(patch.toStdString() + ".tmp/Mods/PMOD/res_mods", patch.toStdString() + "res_mods"); Именно тут происходит SIGABRT

Comment: Ну, например, эта строчка может выбросить исключение, а вы, может быть, его не ловите.

Comment: Даже если я его поймаю переноса уже не будет

Comment: Но программа не упадёт — раз, и вы узнаете, что не так с вашими параметрами — два. (вот документация: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#Error-reporting)

Comment: "boost::filesystem::rename: Каталог не пуст". А как можно сделать перенос в непустую папку с заменой одинаковых файлов?

Comment: О, видите! Уже лучше. Думаю, удалять старый файл за вас буст не будет, придётся самостоятельно проверить и снести.

Comment: А если этих файлов очень много и я несколько разных папок переношу в эту одну, то каждую проверять очень долго

Comment: Очень долго в рантайме? Не может быть. В любом случае проверку на наличие файла должен делать _кто-то_. Если за вас это сделает библиотека, по времени будет то же самое, просто вам на одну строчку меньше писать. Не ленитесь.